# Binding to DataGrid of TabItem not Working using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a small application to help myself learn WPF and MVVM etc. I have been using the example by Josh Smith found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to construct my own application. I have got the application adding `TabItem`s, but the embedded `DataGrid` which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel>` is not showing any data, see the image below:

[image: Example]

The `DataGrid` is the section surrounded in blue. The `UserControl` also seems to be showing the in the tab itself for some reason, but that is not the problem I am asking about here. The `UserControl` contains a `DataGrid` which is bound as follows

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Resources}" 
          dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=searchBox, 
              Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" 
          AlternationCount="2" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
...</DataGrid>
```

The `Resources` property is defined in the `ViewModels` namespace as

```
internal class ResourceDataViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    readonly ResourceDataRepository resourceRepository;
    public ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> Resources { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Where the `ResourceViewmodel` holds the information for each row of the `DataGrid`. I can confirm that the `Resource` property is populated. When I use the same model outside of MVVM and populate `Resource` in the same way it works. **Can someone provide me with and idea of why this could be happening?**

I have attempted to set the explicit path for the binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(viewModels:Resources)}"
```

but this also does not work. Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. To address comments. I set the `DataContext` in the `App.xaml.cs` file by*

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

    // Create the ViewModel to which 
    // the main window binds.
    MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    // When the ViewModel asks to be closed, 
    // close the window.
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = delegate
    {
        mainWindowViewModel.RequestClose -= handler;
        window.Close();
    };
    mainWindowViewModel.RequestClose += handler;

    // Allow all controls in the window to 
    // bind to the ViewModel by setting the 
    // DataContext, which propagates down 
    // the element tree.
    window.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    window.Show();
}
```

*The XAML of the `MainWindow`:*

```
<Window x:Class="ResourceStudio.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Views"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="629.4" Width="814.4">
   <Window.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="284*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="567*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <DockPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" 
                     Background="#FFBEC8D8" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                 Margin="0,0,0.4,0">
         <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                   Background="#FFF9F9F9" 
                   BorderBrush="Black" 
                   KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
               <MenuItem Header="Load _Resource..." 
                         Height="Auto" 
                         Command="{Binding LoadResourceCommand}"/>
               <MenuItem Header="_Add Language..." 
                         Height="Auto"/>
               <Separator/>
               <MenuItem Header="Close _Workspace" 
                         Height="Auto"
                         Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
               <MenuItem Header="E_xit" 
                         Height="Auto" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
            </MenuItem>
         </Menu>
         <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top" MaxHeight="24" Background="#FFF9F9F9">
            <ToolBar Background="#FFF9F9F9">
               <Button ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never">One</Button>
               <Button>Two</Button>
               <Button>Three</Button>
            </ToolBar>
         </ToolBarTray>
      </DockPanel>
      <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0.4,23.6" Grid.RowSpan="2">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
                     Grid.Column="2" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                     Height="Auto" 
                     Width="Auto">
         </TabControl>
      </Grid>
      <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0.4,0.4,-0.4">
         <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF007ACC" Margin="0,2,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Ready" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
         </StatusBarItem>
      </StatusBar>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Where the `MainWindowResources.xaml` is:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.ViewModels"
   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Views"
   >
   <!--This template applies a ResourceControl view to an instance of the 
   ResourceDataViewModel class shown in the main window.-->
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ResourceDataViewModel}">
      <views:ResourceControl/>
   </DataTemplate>

   <!--This template explains how to render the 'Workspace' 
   content area in the main window.-->
   <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
      <TabControl 
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      Margin="4"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*The full code for the `ResourceControl.xaml` is:*

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResourceStudio.Views.ResourceControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:dataAccess="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.DataAccess" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="control">
   <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=control}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <TextBox Text="M"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="searchBox" />
      <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
         <Border BorderBrush="#FF007ACC" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(viewModels:Resources)}" 
                      dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=searchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" AlternationCount="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
               <DataGrid.Resources>
                  <dataAccess:SearchValueConverter x:Key="searchValueConverter"/>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                     <Setter Property="dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                        <Setter.Value>
                           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource searchValueConverter}">
                              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                           </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                        </Trigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
               </DataGrid.Resources>
               <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF007ACC"/>
                           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
               </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            </DataGrid>
         </Border>
      </Grid>
   </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

*The `TextBox` is bound to the `DataGrid`. When the user types into that `TextBox` the `DataGrid` filters and highlights the cells which contains the required text. This however, is not the problem and this code works, it is just the binding to the `DataGrid` I am interested in. Thanks again for tour time.*

*Edit2: According to @dkozl's comments I have removed the `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=control}"` from the `DockPanel` declaration, so we now have*

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
...
```

*and in the `MainWindowResource.xaml` I now have*

```
<ResourceDictionary 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.ViewModels"
   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Views"
   >
   <!--This template applies a ResourceControl view to an instance of the 
   ResourceDataViewModel class shown in the main window.-->
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ResourceDataViewModel}">
      <views:ResourceControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
   </DataTemplate>

   <!--This template explains how to render the 'Workspace' 
   content area in the main window.-->
   <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
      <TabControl 
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      Margin="4"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*This has not worked. That is my `DataGrid` in the `ResourceControl` is not being populated. Thanks again for your time it is most appreciated...*

Comment: Can you provide code about how you set the `DataContext`-Property in the window?

Comment: Is that "M" in a `TextBox` above the `DataGid` also bound to some property of `ResourceDataViewModel` class?

Comment: @Herdo I have updated the question with the requested information. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: @dkozl Yes, I have placed an initial 'M' for testing. Yes, the text box is bound to the `DataGrid`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looking at your example, I know it's a bit of a long shot but did you try changing visibility of your `ResourceDataViewModel` class to public `public class ResourceDataViewModel`?

Comment: Yes, in fact I have. I will do it again now to make sure...

Comment: Your user control `<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=control}"` is bound to control itself and this does not make any sense. I would try and remove that `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=control}"` part and change your `DataTemplate` to `<views:ResourceControl DataContext={Binding}"/>` so each `UserControl` will be bound to separate item

Comment: Replace `{Binding Path=(viewModels:Resources)}` by `{Binding Resources}`. Also try to add some items to this collection in the default constructor just for testing purposes.

Comment: @vortex in the question I have stated that I have tried both of these permutations. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Did it work with the suggested `DataContext` changes from my comment above? Basically the problem is that you bind `UserControl` `DockPanel.DataContext` to `ResourceControl` control and not `ResourceDataViewModel` class. What you need to do instead is to bind `DataContext` of `ResourceControl` in your `DataTemplate`

Comment: @dkozl I have update the question to illustrate what I have done, I believe according to your comments.

Comment: Had to extrapolate, as some things were missing, but generally it's your code, and it works fine - binds items to `DataGrid` [Download](http://db.tt/YDgg1cMQ)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I will take a detailed look after work as this is a personal project. I can't thank you enough for your help...

Comment: @dkozl I have checked the code you have uploaded, and I understand it. However, what I have done seems to use all the mechanisms you have. I am really confused over what is wrong, would you be willing to actually look at my code? I could offer you rep payment as a bounty?

Comment: Sure, upload ZIP somewhere so I can take a look.

Comment: @dkozl thanks very much. I have uploaded it to [The SkyDrive](http://sdrv.ms/19UqB3E). The application idea is to help edit and update C# resources. I have included a .resx that can be loaded in using the File menu. You should see that the `Resources` `ObservableCollection` is being populated, why this is not working is killing me. Thanks you very much once again...

Comment: I could send you back your code but there were only 2 small changes. 1) to make bind property, as @vortex suggested, you need to change `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(viewModels:Resources)}"` to `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources}"` 2) if currently throws an exception in `ResourceViewModel.Error` as type case is invalid

Comment: Got it!! If you provide an answer with what you have said above, I will give you some rep to say thanks :]! One last thing. Can you see why a `ResourceControl` is being added to the `Tab` header and the tab body - this is also confusing me?

Comment: It's because you apply `DataTemplate` to your class type and in this case tab header content and tab content are the same thing so same template applies. Delete your `DataTemplate` for `viewModels:ResourceDataViewModel` type and put this directly into your main `TabControl`: `<TabControl.ContentTemplate><DataTemplate><views:ResourceControl/></DataTemplate></TabControl.ContentTemplate>`. Should solve your issue

Comment: sorry should be `<views:ResourceControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserControl` `DockPanel.DataContext` is bound to `ResourceControl` control and not to `ResourceDataViewModel` class. What you need to do instead is to bind `DataContext` of `ResourceControl` in your `DataTemplate`. To achive that first remove `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=control}"` from `ResourceControl.DockPanel` and then bind `ResourceControl.DataContext` to your object by `<views:ResourceControl DataContext={Binding}"/>`. Also you need to change `DataGrid` items binding from `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(viewModels:Resources)}"` to `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources}"`.

Not part of the original question but same template applies to tab header and tab content because `DataTemplate` is type specific and in this case tab header content and tab content is the same thing. To solve the issue remove `DataTemplate` for `viewModels:ResourceDataViewModel` type and put this directly into your main `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <views:ResourceControl DataContext={Binding}"/>
   </DataTemplat‌​e>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: This is eligible for a bounty in 35min. I will give you some XP for your trouble... All the best and once again, thanks.